# How would I save a Jmeter response that is an image?

Tags: java, jmeter

I have some requests going to a web app. In one of the requests, the server responds with just an image (jpeg). How would I download this image? I have a Bean script sampler going for text responses but I can't see an option for images.

Comment: Have you tried Add->Listener->'Save Response To File'?

Comment: What does your BeanShell Sampler look like? Can you post the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you targeting to do it via Beanshell take the following steps:

1. Add a [Beanshell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the request which returns the image
2. Put the following code into the PostProcessor's "Script" area

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
   FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(new File("/path/to/the/file.jpg"),data);
   ```

Where `data` is the pre-defined Beanshell variable holding byte array representing parent sampler response.

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more tips and tricks and a kind of Beanshell cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

Use **Save Response to a file** under the **Listener** section.
Only thing you need to add is the path where you want the image